# How do I password protect an Apache website?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I added this to my `.htaccess` file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/the/directory/you/are/protecting/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

and this to the `.htpasswd` file:

```
username:password
```

However, it is not working. It doesn't prompt me for login.

Answer (score 4):

Your **.htaccess** file looks fine.  The only reason it is not working as you have it is that Apache is configured to ignore it.

In your apache config, ideally in the sites-* config file, add:

```
<Directory /path/to/the/directory/you/are/protecting/>
      AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
```

The **[AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)** directive is what allows the htaccess file to function.  By default, most Apache setups have it turned off (set to *None* actually), including Ubuntu/Debian.

In your **.htpasswd** file, the password must be encrypted.  You can do this most easily using the htpasswd tool that mezgani suggested.  It will look like this if you read the file:

```
bob:abJnggxhB/yWI
```

With the **AllowOverride** directive set to at least *AuthConfig*, your .htaccess file in place, and your .htpasswd containing a user with an encrypted password, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

First, add this following to your apache config:

```
<Directory /path/to/the/directory/you/are/protecting/>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        deny from all
        Order deny,allow
</Directory>
```

After, you may create the .htpasswd file that will contain your login and password with htpasswd command and not manually

```
htpasswd -c /path/to/the/directory/you/are/protecting/.htpasswd username
```

I think that moving the .htpasswd file somewhere different from the path of the directory that you are protecting is more secure.

Also, For security reasons, please read this article on [securityfocus](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/9874/discuss)

Comment: how do you remove it later ?

Comment: Delete the .htaccess and .htpasswd files. and don't forget to remove the apache config that you've added

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: You will need to add a `require valid-user` below the Order line. The current apache configuration is set to deny from everyone.

Comment: yes. i did that. still doesn't work.

Comment: well i added these in my sites-available.

.htaccess is not recognized.

Comment: I must say I also have this problem and nowhere near a solution after 5 hours. Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 1):

In Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6), changing the AllowOverride in httpd.conf only enables .htaccess protection in the main web pages (/Library/WebServer by default).  Enabling it for individual users' ~/Sites folders is controlled by a separate .conf file for each user.  On my systems this is under /etc/apache/users .  Jeff Snider's reference to "in the sites-*" may be where the files for individual users' pages are configured on his system.