# Setting up a password protected download page on an OS X server

Tags: mac-osx, website, password-protected

I need to setup a password protected download webpage on my OS X server, can anyone link me to some good resources that might help me do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Mac OS X serves pages using Apache. You can either set up 'Basic' authentication by editing `.htaccess` by hand or you can do it using Server Admin. Apple uses the term Realm in Server Admin to refer to this.

Doing it by hand see Question 74906 ([How Do I password protect an Apache website?](https://serverfault.com/questions/74906/how-do-i-password-protect-an-apache-website))

Server Admin (GUI) Instructions (from the [Documentation](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/Web_Tech_Admin_v10.6.pdf)):

> 1. Open Server Admin and connect to the server.
> 2. Click the triangle at the left of the server.
> 3. The list of services appears. From the expanded Servers list, select Web.
> 4. Click Sites, then select the website in the list.
> 5. Click Realms below the websites list.
> 6. Click the Add (+) button to create a realm.
>      The realm is the part of the website users can access.
> 7. In the Realm Name field, enter the realm name.
>      This is the name users see when they log in to the website.
> 8. From the Authentication pop-up menu, choose a method of authentication:
>
>    - Basic authentication is on by default. Don’t use basic authentication for sensitive data because it sends your password to the server unencrypted.
>    - Digest authentication is more secure than basic authentication because it uses an encrypted hash of your password.
>    - Kerberos authentication is the most secure authentication. If you want Kerberos authentication, you must join the server to a Kerberos realm.
> 9. Enter the realm location or folder you are restricting access to:
>
>    - Choose Location from the pop-up menu and enter a URL to the location in the website that you want to restrict access to.
>    - Choose Folder from the pop-up menu and enter the path to the folder that you want to restrict access to.
>        You can also click the Browse button to locate the folder you want to use.
> 10. Click OK.
> 11. Select the new realm and click Add (+) to open the Users & Groups window. To switch between the Users list and the Groups list, click Users or Groups in the window.
> 12. To add users or groups to a realm, drag users to the Users & Groups column on the right of the Realms pane.
>       When users or members of a group you’ve added to the realm connect to the site, they must supply their user name and password.
> 13. Limit realm access to specified users and groups by setting the following permissions using the up and down arrows in the Permissions column:
>
>     - Browse Only: Permits users or groups to browse the website. Â    Browse and Read WebDAV: Permits users or groups to browse the website and also
>         read the website files using WebDAV.
>     - Browse and Read/Write WebDAV: Permits users or groups to browse the website and also read and write to website files using WebDAV.
>     - None: Prevents users or groups from using any permissions. Click Save.
>         Use the Realms pane to delete a user or group by selecting the name and clicking the Delete (–) button.

(Page 39)

Comment: I had tried many more complicated solutions that did not work at all and this was simple and worked, thanks a lot!